# How to make hyperlinks clickable in markdown mode?

Tags: org-mode, markdown-mode

In an emacs org-mode buffer it is possible to type a hyperlink and then click on the hyperlink with a mouse to open the url in an external browser.

Is there a way for markdown mode to have active hyperlinks as well?

Comment: Have you seen [how to export](http://orgmode.org/manual/Markdown-export.html) org-mode doc to markdown? Alternatively, you can use [pandoc](http://pandoc.org) to export org-mode doc to markdown with a few more customizations (to the links, for example).

Comment: If you have the point on the hyperlink, you can also `M-x ffap` (short for find file at point) and it opens the default browser with the url at point. (but goto-address-mode is the good answer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the [current development version](https://github.com/jrblevin/markdown-mode) of [Markdown mode](http://jblevins.org/projects/markdown-mode/), links are now clickable without requiring any additional libraries.  URLs can also be hidden, and you can hover your mouse pointer to see the URL and optional title text.

Comment: More specifically, either `^C ^X ^L` or `M-x markdown-toggle-url-hiding` or add `(markdown-toggle-url-hiding t)` to your `markdown-mode-hook`

Answer (score 9):

This isn't easy enough to find, but what you want is [goto-address-mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Goto-Address-mode.html). You can activate it in the current buffer with `M-x goto-address-mode` or you can add it to markdown-mode-hook:

```
(defun turn-on-goto-address-mode ()
   (goto-address-mode 1))
(add-hook 'markdown-mode-hook #'turn-on-goto-address-mode)
```

Comment: Thanks. Two notes from goto-addr.el. 1. Suggested use is (add-hook 'mh-show-mode-hook 'goto-address) 2. If the buffer is fontified after goto-address-fontify is run (say, using font-lock-fontify-buffer), then font-lock faces will override goto-address faces.

Comment: Ah! Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, here's the setup I use now to make clickable hyperlinks in prog-mode (useful for URLs within comments) and text-mode (which includes markdown).

```
(use-package goto-addr
  :bind
  (:map goto-address-highlight-keymap
        ("C-c C-o" . goto-address-at-point))
  :hook ((prog-mode . goto-address-prog-mode)
         (text-mode . goto-address-mode)))
```

Answer (score -1):

> In an emacs org-mode buffer it is possible to type a hyperlink and then click on the hyperlink with a mouse to open the url in an external browser.

**Yes this can be done without any additional code**.

The format in which you have enter URLs in `org-mode` file is
`[[http://www.google.co.in][Google India]]`. This will open the webpage (in your default browser) on a click event.

This is how it looks in my org file
[image: Hyperlink in org-mode]
[Manual reference](http://orgmode.org/guide/Link-format.html#Link-format)

Comment: The question is about markdown mode, not about exports.

Comment: You're right. I answered the first part of the question right. I misunderstood the second part. Edited my answer to remove the markdown portion